# How do I ask for less permissions in Facebook SDK 3.1?

Tags: ios6, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to implement Facebook SDK 3.1 in our app, strictly for the purpose of allowing the user to post about our app on their own wall.  We don't want any of the user's information at all.  We just want them to enjoy using the app so much that they share about it so other people buy it and download it.

I followed the instructions on the following Facebook page for getting started and also Facebook Login:

https://developers.facebook.com/ios/features/whats-new-ios-sdk-3.1/

On a device running iOS 6.0, I was disappointed to see that the following code block, which is supposed to be requesting basic info:

```
- (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
}
```

Results in the following UIAlertView dialog message being displayed to the user:

```
"App Name" would like to access your basic profile info and list of friends.
```

As an end user, I would wonder why this app needs a list of my friends.  And actually, our app doesn't need a list of friends and would be concerned that the app would start spamming my friends (like so many apps really do that we give permissions to).

Again, pretending like I am an end user, after reluctantly giving privileges I go to a browser and access my Account Settings in Facebook and choose Apps.  Then I select the app I just gave access to.  It says the following:

This app needs:

```
  Your email address
  Your birthday
  Your location
```

Again, the app doesn't need those things.

On the same App Settings page in Facebook, it has a "Last Data Access" -> "See Details" option.  When I click that it says the following:

```
Last Data Access
In the last 90 days, "App Name" accessed the following information on your behalf:
Basic Information
Education History, Current City and Work History
```

The plot thickens!  My app doesn't need Education History, Current City and Work History.

The reason this bothers me is that I believe users will turn down these access requests because they don't understand why my app needs all of these things.

How do I truly go after minimal privileges such that I can allow the user to post from our app about our app on their own wall?

Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Comment: Click the 'basic information' popup on a regular permissions dialog, you'll be brought here: https://www.facebook.com/about/privacy/your-info-on-other#applications - part of this explains that basic information includes `your User ID, as well your friends' User IDs (or your friend list) and your public information.`

Comment: Igy,thanks that link was very helpful.  It may not be intuitive to me what Facebook is doing but at least I now know it is not a mistake with how I am programming this.  Thanks!  Would like to give you a checkmark, but it looks like you added a comment versus an answer.  Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Even though info might be public it should not be mentioned in the fb-app settings if my app does NOT use it. Sincerely hope facebook can change this behaviour. In fact i hope they add a feature to only ask for a valid facebook ID instead of the current minimum of basic profile info. Also the publish_actions access is up for discussion. Why can you not propose a like or a wall post to a user and have him accept instead of needing full access to publish to his feed at any time you want. You can via native ios or via webdialog but they do NOT support likes without 'publish_actions' permissions!

Comment: I don't understand why this question was "closed as not a real question". The question is "how to I ask for less perms" and the answer is "facebook don't let you". I was just wondering the same thing and came across this page, and found the answer in the comment to be useful.